# .cmd program starts files in a command prompt

Tags: batch-file, macros, cmd

I have a simple script to change a file name and open an excel macro concerning said file to do operations on it. When i run it, the file opens in a command prompt titled, "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness.xls" instead of the actual file.Code follows:

```
if exist "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness.xls" (
    msg "%username%" Please move the current FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness.xls file
    quit
)
if exist qcprint.txt (
    if exist qcprint.csv (
        del qcprint.csv
        rename "qcprint.txt" qcprint.csv
        start "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness backup.xlsm"
    ) else (
        rename "qcprint.txt" qcprint.csv
        start "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness backup.xlsm"
    )
) else (
    if exist qcprint.csv (
        start "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness backup.xlsm"
    ) else (
        msg "%username%" Please load the "qcprint.txt" file to the flash drive.
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the `start` command (abridged, see `start /?` for the full syntax) is:

```
start ["title"] [command/program] [parameters]
```

If your `[command/program]` is in quotes, `start` thinks it is the title, and since it sees no program, just starts a command window.

The solution:

```
start "" "FM-001761-01 Substrate Thickness backup.xlsm"
```